# ora-01858 a non numeric charcter was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```sql
select *
from   cron_log_razorpay
where   trunc(To_Date(Crtd_Dt, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) = trunc(sysdate)
order by crtd_dt desc;
```

the data type of `crtd_dt` is `varchar(100)`,
i hot the error fix the input data or the date format model

Comment: If your datatype is varchar it looks like you're using a format mask that is different to your nls_date_format parameter or because the event_occurrence column contains data that isn't a number.

Comment: so how do i resolve this issue can you guide

Comment: Don't store dates as strings. Now you'll have to find invalid values and fix them first so that you could apply that format model to TO_DATE function.

Comment: can you give some examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your table so you store dates as dates.

```sql
ALTER TABLE cron_log_razorpay ADD Crtd_Dt2 DATE;

UPDATE cron_log_razorpay
SET Crtd_Dt2 = TO_DATE(
                 Crtd_Dt DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
                 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
               )
WHERE Crtd_Dt2 IS NULL;
```

Then review the columns that failed:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   cron_log_razorpay
WHERE  Crtd_Dt2 IS NULL;
```

and, if necessary, fix the strings in `Crtd_dt` and re-run the `UPDATE`.

Then you could replace the `Crtd_Dt` column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE cron_log_razorpay DROP COLUMN Crtd_Dt;
ALTER TABLE cron_log_razorpay RENAME COLUMN Crtd_Dt2 TO Crtd_Dt;
```

Then all your values will be valid dates (or `NULL` values if you have not fixed your data).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ntEWbiDa)